# How do i center a header link in CSS?

Tags: css

So im designing a website in CSS and im trying to center my navigation bar (A Header with links) but when i use the "text-align : center" and "Margin : auto" properties it doesnt work. Here is my HTML file code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
         content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Brickwood Fire Dept. - Established 2008</title>
    <link type="text/css"
         rel="stylesheet" href="main_style.css" media="screen"
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>
    Brickwood Fire Department
  </h1>
  <h2>
    Established 2008
  </h2>
  <h3>
    <a class = "home" href = "http://www.brickwoodfiredept.weebly.com">Home</a>
    <a href = "http://www.brickwoodfiredept.weebly.com/contact-us">Contact</a>
    <a href = "http://www.brickwoodfiredept.weebly.com/media.html">Media</a>
    <a href = "http://www.brickwoodfiredept.weebly.com/links">Links</a>
    <a href = "http://www.brickwoodfiredept.weebly.com/newsletter">Newsletter</a>
  </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
a {
  color : white ;
  background : #32C1DA ;
  width : 30% ;
  text-align : center ;
  font-family : Arial ;
  font-size : 150% ;
  margin : auto ;
  word-spacing : normal
}
```

The rest of the CSS code is left out to save space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this
    h3 { width : 30% ; text-align : center ;  } 
    a { color : white ; background : #32C1DA ; width : 30% ; text-align : center ; font-
        family : Arial ; font-size : 150% ; margin : auto ; word-spacing : normal }

Answer (score 3):

try putting the text-align on the h3 tag not the a tag.

```
h3 { text-align:center; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer is:

```
h3 {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
display:block;
```

to your css

Comment: The only problem is i want them to be layed out like this: "Home   Blah   Blah   Blah   Blah".

Answer (score 0):

You need `margin:auto;` on the parent (h3 tag) and `text-align:center;` on the child (a tag).

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. I think Phillip was trying to say this, but didnt word it correctly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1621272 You can click the up arrow on useful answers and the checkmark next to the answer you believe to be correct.